# Can you strike an enemy in melee with an implement?

Tags: dnd-4e, implements, improvised-weaponry

The warlock in my group fell off a ladder and lost an arm. Where he used to have both a dagger and an implement, he can hold only his implement (rod) now.

Can he, both mechanically and realistically take a swing at an adjacent enemy with the rod, possibly as an improvised weapon? Can this be done with any implement?

Comment: What did he fall *onto* that he lost an arm? A wood chipper? What happened to magical healing?

Comment: I agree with Oblivious Sage, the original situation you are describing isn't something 4e covers in its rules in any sense. 

If your DM is forcing this on you and you feel like going along with it multiclass to use staff or dagger implements which as Glen Nelson points out are already weapons.

Comment: I didn't find details necessary, but the full story is that the character was pretty much killed (I'm the GM) in a fight. I let him keep the character, but with a serious wound (he's got some dex penalties, but doesn't mind it much).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Improvised weapons are described as:

> Any small melee - [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=item&id=3560)
>
> Improvised one-handed melee weapon
>
> Cost: — gp
>
> Damage: 1d4
>
> Weight: 1–5 lb.
>
> Improvised weapons include anything you happen to pick up, from a rock to a chair.

This would apply to any implement except a Staff and anything already a weapon. Staff's can be used as quarterstaves, and weapons you would use as weapons.

Also note, there is an at-will warlock power for melee combat, called [Eldritch Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7402), in PH Heroes: Series 1.